# How do I get the floor of the current time to an hour?

Tags: go

Assuming current time is 3:41:19, I would like to "floor" the timestamp to 3:00:00.
For example, the current time in unix is:

```
now := time.Now().Unix()
```

How do I get the floor to an hour in the same format?

Comment: [`time.Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate)?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Truncate](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate):

```
now := time.Now()
onHour := now.Truncate(time.Hour)
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/IIGHVBFBQqP)</kbd>

Do note from the docs:

> It does not operate on the presentation form of the time. Thus, Truncate(Hour) may return a time with a non-zero minute, depending on the time's Location.

So using `UTC` timezone location would avoid unexpected surprises.

Comment: Tried this: 

`
func main() {
 now := time.Now()
 onHour := now.Truncate(time.Hour)
 before := onHour.Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(-3))
 fmt.Println("now:", now)
 fmt.Println("hours:", onHour)
 fmt.Println("before:", before)
}
`

However, the output is
```
now: 2021-03-02 13:55:28.345999 +0530 IST m=+0.000094386
hours: 2021-03-02 13:30:00 +0530 IST
before: 2021-03-02 10:30:00 +0530 IST
```